# Why template functions cannot deduce brace initializers, but auto-declared variables can?

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, type-deduction

As anyone knows, when a brace initializer is passed directly to a template function, the type cannot be deduced and the compilation fails:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T)
{
   // do something
}

f({ 1,2,3 }); // compilation fails.
```

But, if you declare a variable using auto and initialize it with a braced
initializer, the type deduction works fine and the deduced type is `std::initializer_list<T>`.

```
auto arr = { 1,2,3 }; // works fine
```

Now the question is why there is such an inconsistency in the C++ standard? What will go wrong, if templates can deduce brace initializers into `std::initializer_list<T>`?

**Note:** There are so many questions on SO from developers that face the deduction of initializer lists for template functions (e.g [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757614/why-doesnt-my-template-accept-an-initializer-list), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241370/deduce-template-argument-for-size-of-initializer-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119140/template-argument-deduction-fails-when-using-braced-initializer-list)). But I cannot find any Q/A about the exact reason behind this decision.

Comment: @downvoters: Please kindly let me know what is wrong with the Q.